# Wordpress: disable removing <p> and <br> tags from inserted comments

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, comments, strip-tags

I want to add a WYSIWYG editor to our WP comments. I used the [trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) js plugin. I do not want to use a WP plugin for it because I want to keep the code as small as possible.

When I save the comment, all **p** and **br** tags get stripped. Other tags like **strong** are saved to the WP database.

I tried several things like removing the wpautop filter.

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop', 99);
```

Or showing the comments with

```
echo nl2br($comment->comment_content);
```

or

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', $comment->comment_content, 1005);
```

It looks like WordPress is stripping the tags before saving the comment. It does so with wp_insert_comment but also with wp_update_comment. I tested the result comming from the editor before saving and this shows the content with all the p and br tags in it.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Refer this link, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15394/extra-tinymce-editor-strips-p-and-br-tags

Comment: Thank you very much for this link. I finally solved it with the "preprocess_comment" filter. I filtered through the commentdata and added the wpautop function:                 
                                $commentdata['comment_content'] = wpautop($commentdata['comment_content']);

Comment: Good to hear this. Cheers Thijs van lersel.